# Flutter firebase google login and email/password auth problem

Tags: flutter

I have implemented firebase email/pass auth in my app. Also firebase google login. I want to add validator.
If i create user by email/pass and then i try to google login by same gmail my email/pass user account are remove and creating a new google login user account. I want if already email/pass user has been created it will not create google login on same gmail.

Here is my google login method. How can i implement this validator?

Answer (score 1):

On the (user side) client side in Flutter, when the user tries to sign in with Google, First check if the email address associated with the Google account already exists in your Firebase Auth database.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email: email).then((methods) {
  if (methods.contains("password")) {
    //User already login with Email and password method. 
    //say go and login with that method
  } else {
    // creating a new user account
  }
});
```